# issue with UIButton background borders iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a UIButton in my app with a background image, this one

[image]

I want to make it longer, and added the following to my code:

```
UIImage *backgroundButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"];
        [backgroundButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
        [backgroundButton imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];

        [self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:[backgroundButton imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I tried to put some kind of margins for avoiding this

[image]

How can I get the same result of the first button but with this size?
Thanks in advance for the support

---

**EDIT*****

I'm going to put both methods provided for our developers

Jesus:

```
[self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 8, 10, 8)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

gameCon:

```
UIImage *modifiedBackgroundButton = [backgroundButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
        [self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:[modifiedBackgroundButton imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [backgroundButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
        [backgroundButton imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

I like both answers Jesus is very precise and gameCon used my own code for helping me thank you all for your help!!!

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see your stretched background image actually does not have cap insets set.
You have to store and work on results of this methods (this code actually does nothing):

```
[backgroundButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[backgroundButton imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
```

So the proper approach would be:

```
UIImage *modifiedBackgroundButton = [backgroundButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];
[self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:[modifiedBackgroundButton imageWithAlignmentRectInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self.loginButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```